# Machine Learning - Finding best cars to resell

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I have gathered used car data and their prices from two diffrent websites. Then I have cleaned the data so it has the same columns for both sites. The columns are as follows:

`brand  | model | year | kilometers | transmission | gas_type | type | price`

Using scikit-learn Decision Tree Classifier, how can I predict, which cars would best to resell for one site to another?

I have used the classifer to predict the future prices, and got most important features for price for each dataset, but I'm not sure how I can find a perfect car to resell or how can I find the best parameters that would result in car being cheap on one site and expensive on the other?

Comment: Can you explain more please , i mean what do you want to have as an output ?

Comment: As an output I would like to get brand name, model, year, kilometers, transmission and type that would tell us that this kind of car would be cheap to buy on one site, and we could resell it for the highest profit on the other site. In other words: we could buy a car on one site for a 1000 dollars and then resell it for 1200 dollars on the other site.

Comment: I get it now , I answered your question

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can't do this with Decision Tree , i wont say it's impossible , of course it is *like predicting for each time one column* , but it will be hard to apply and long , or even sometimes meaningless

I can suggest you a way to do this using **Recurrent Neural Network** with **LSTM** , this kind of model has the possibility to make 4 kinds of prediction `{ one to one , one to many , many to one , many to many }` and in your case you can use one to many : **Giving the price as input , and getting the brand name, model, year, kilometers, transmission and type as output**

Of course you wont do it in same way of Decision Tree , Neural Networks takes only numbers so you'll have to look for ways to make transformations